# Answer got downvoted but user removed the question

Tags: discussion, downvoting

So I answered a question about a Internet connection problem where the connection worked but there was no Internet. Naturally I suggested to check the DNS settings and I got my answer downvoted.. A short while later though, the asker removed the question (maybe after checking his DNS settings). I didn't get any points back though I don't think. Is this the way it is supposed to work?

Comment: Do you still have a link to the question/answer involved? Look in your browser history. 10k+ rep users (like me) can still see those deleted posts so perhaps someone can help you better with that link provided.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is.

Try not to worry about the little stuff.  I am glad more and more people are trying to help, but remember you should be here to help and be helped.  The points are just a silly thing we use to give people an idea of their knowledge.

When I first came to the community I got upset about loosing some points, but it happens and sometimes I really did just make a mistake.

Comment: Yeah I know, it's just when you start out as a newer user you can't even do simple things like upvote and downvote when you have no reputation.

Comment: Just give it a time the point system is important to the quality and to keep out spammers.  It actually does help even if it kind of sucks for us normal humans.  It took me like 3 me a few days of helping others until I could actually use most the site functions.  Sometimes people also don't respond to your help for a few days.

Comment: It happens. I see a wrong answer with no downvotes, but the correct answer downvoted. What saddens me I see a  lack of comments by downvoters or suggested edits to help improve answers and this is more important than the scores IMHO.

Comment: Yes! It took half a week of heavy question-answering to get various features that I wanted/needed to answer questions better (comments, anyone? :) )